# litedb database file size keeps increasing although deleting data

Tags: c#, litedb

There are two applications,

- one console application keeps writing data to a litedb database continuously.
- The other console application reads data and deletes whatever was read

```
var liteCollection = _liteDb.GetCollection<SomeClass>("ColName");

var data = liteCollection.FindAll().ToList();

//prepare list if id's and delete
var ids = data .Select(l => l.Id).ToList();
var count = liteCollection.DeleteMany(rp => ids.Contains(rp.Id));
```

Everything looks great, but the database file size keeps growing and is *not* reducing at all. How to shrink the database?

I get to know some `shrink` command, but how to use it? A `liteDb.Shrink()` option I am not seeing and is not available.

- Is there any API available to shrink the database and how to use it?
- The above read and delete code I am running in loops which call every 5 minutes, can I use Shrink as well right after delete?
- Is my predicate right for `DeleteMany` or is there another way to do this as well?

Comment: The method you are looking for is called `Rebuild`. See https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/blob/master/LiteDB.Tests/Engine/Rebuild_Tests.cs